# How to give name inside li and show image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've seen some websites where we give li and the image shows up:

Ex. `<li>skype</li>`

Just by giving this the skype icon shows up. This is really amazing. How is this possible? I went into Firebug and didn't find any `background` inside CSS.

Could anybody please tell suggest what purpose would this serve and why would anybody use that?

**Edit:** As an example, see this website:

http://www.burakson.com/

and see this HTML: `<a class="s1 btip" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/boureaque">Facebook</a>`

How would that HTML show facebook icon?

Comment: Perhaps it's using `:before`

Comment: Which website are you referring to?

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Sorry for incomplete info, please read my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you later specified in the question's not using `:before` or web font stuff, it's just simple css:

```
.head-social ul li a {
    background: transparent url('../images/socials.png') no-repeat top left;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

The `background` line sets the icon image and the `text-indent: -9999px;` line makes the text inside to be invisible.

And for each icon, there're styles like this:

```
.head-social ul li a.s1 {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.head-social ul li a.s2 {
    background-position: -30px 0;
}
```

which override `background-position` for each icon element.

Further readings:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-indent
2. https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS+sprite